# SWT Character to stateMask and KeyCode

Tags: java, swt

I do have a character, lets say '/' and I want it to be converted to the keyCode and StateMask:

'/' --> StateMask = 131072   , KeyCode = 55

Is there a function I am not aware of which can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to do some sort of verification in a `Text` or similar.

First, a little lecture about `KeyEvent`s:

`stateMask`

> the state of the keyboard modifier keys and mouse masks at the time the event was generated.

`keyCode`

> the key code of the key that was typed, as defined by the key code constants in class SWT. When the character field of the event is ambiguous, this field contains the unicode value of the original character. For example, typing Ctrl+M or Return both result in the character '\r' but the keyCode field will also contain '\r' when Return was typed.

In your case it seems like you want to compare the entered character to `/`. `stateMask` and `keyCode` aren't necessary in this scenario. Simply do `e.character == '/'`. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if (!(e.character == '/'))
                e.doit = false;
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

Just a note: The values of `stateMask` and `keyCode` are `0` and `47` respectively here on my machine (Windows 7, UK keyboard layout).

Comment: Hi Baz, thanks for your answer and sorry I was too unprecise. In our application we really calculate the stateMask and keyCode out of a String, e.g. "Alt+/". This conversion is not always correct, so I was looking for a already working utility function. Are the keyCodes the same accross the operating systems?

Comment: @matthias What do you need them for? I'm pretty sure that the keyCode and stateMask of each character depend on the keyboard layout as you can see in the note below my answer.

Comment: So, keyCodes for a character are not unique across the OS?

Comment: @matthias Not sure. I can't test it here just now, but the values I got for the slash (`/`) differ from those you had in your question which leads me to my assumption.